# Open file from a php document, and close it from another?

Tags: php, file, session, session-variables

I am trying to do the following:

Open a file, say "myfile.json" from a php- let's call it "utils.php"; Use it in other php pages; close it from another php.

I have tried to include "utils.php" in the other files and write in the utils file, but it does not seem to work. I suppose this happens because utils.php is never actually executed, only included, but if I should execute it, how can I do it without having to refresh any page, preferably right when the user gets on the main page? This should not be seen by the user, what he sees should remain the main page.

Thanks in advance, I am quite new to php, and am trying to learn.

Comment: What is it you want to write into `utils.php`?

Comment: php resources are automatically closed as soon as the script finishes running. The best way I can see this happening is if you run a script as a server that accepts connections, then you could open close the resource on the "server" like script instead of your http script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a file, you are running all code inside it. The functions and classes will not be evaluated but will be defined for future use. If you open your file as this example:

```
util.php

    <?php 

    $file_hand = fopen('/tmp/file.txt','r');
```

You will have a handle if the operation is completed. However, the variable $file_hand is global. If you need to use a function to close it, you will need the following code to do it:

```
other.php
function close_file(){
    global $file_hand;
    fclose($file_hand)
}
```

or you can pass the handle as parameter like:

```
function close_file($file_hand){
    fclose($file_hand)
}
```

Doesn't matter how you will close the file. You have to make sure the variable you are using is the same created in utils.php. If you close like this:

```
function close_file(){
    fclose($file_hand)
}
```

The variable you've created in until.php file is different of this one.

Comment: I think I've done something else wrong. I've tried something like this, but the error was actually in utils. So I thought I was doing something wrong when I included it and the variables were actually not defined. Thank you